# troubleshoot openVINO model output for cv2 rectangle

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, openvino

I am experimenting with this [openVINO Zoo model](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/tree/master/models/intel/person-detection-asl-0001#person-detection-asl-0001) for person detection. What I am stuck on is if I am handling the model architecture correctly. This is the info for the [model input](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/tree/master/models/intel/person-detection-asl-0001#outputs) and [model output](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/tree/master/models/intel/person-detection-asl-0001#outputs). (all 3 links are to the same page but different locations)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from openvino.runtime import Core

MODEL = "person-detection-asl-0001"
PRECISION = "FP16"
MODEL_PATH = "./person-detection-asl-0001/"
CHAR = "/"
FILE_TYPE = ".xml"
FULL_MODEL_STR = MODEL_PATH + CHAR + PRECISION + CHAR + MODEL + FILE_TYPE

print("testing model")
print(FULL_MODEL_STR)

ie_core = Core()


def model_init(model_path):
    model = ie_core.read_model(model=model_path)
    compiled_model = ie_core.compile_model(model=model, device_name="CPU")
    input_keys = compiled_model.input(0)
    output_keys = compiled_model.output(0)
    return input_keys, output_keys, compiled_model


input_key, output_keys, compiled_model = model_init(FULL_MODEL_STR)
print("COMPILED MODEL: ", compiled_model)


# Get input size - Recognition.
height, width = list(input_key.shape)[2:]
print("MODEL DIMENSIONS: ", (height, width))

image = cv2.imread("./ben_sarah.JPG")
# cv2.imshow("image",image)


image_mod = cv2.resize(image, (width, height))
image_mod = image_mod.transpose((2, 0, 1))
image_mod = image_mod.reshape(1, 3, height, width)


# Run inference.
boxes = compiled_model([image_mod])[compiled_model.output('boxes')]
print(f"{MODEL} BOXES.SHAPE: {boxes.shape}")

def postprocess(result, image):

    aligns = image.shape

    detections = result.reshape(-1, 5)
    for i, detection in enumerate(detections):
        xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, confidence = detection
        if confidence > 0.2:
            xmin = int(max((xmin * image.shape[1]), 10))
            ymin = int(max((ymin * image.shape[0]), 10))
            xmax = int(min((xmax * image.shape[1]), image.shape[1] - 10))
            ymax = int(min((ymax * image.shape[0]), image.shape[0] - 10))

            conf = round(confidence, 2)
            print(f"conf: {conf:.2f}")
            print((xmin, ymin),(xmax, ymax))

            # For bounding box
            cv2.rectangle(image, (xmin, ymin),
                          (xmax, ymax), (255, 255, 255), 5)

            # For the text background
            # Finds space required
            (w, h), _ = cv2.getTextSize(
                f"{conf:.2f}", cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.7, 1)

            # Prints the text.
            cv2.rectangle(image, (xmin, ymin + h + 5),
                          (xmin + w + 5, ymin), (255, 255, 255), -1)
            cv2.putText(image, f"{conf:.2f}", (xmin, ymin + h),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.7, (0, 0, 0), 3)

    return image

final = postprocess(boxes, image)
cv2.imwrite(f"./outputs/{PRECISION}-{MODEL}.png", final)
cv2.imshow("final", final)
```

The code runs...but the model output for creating a box around a detected human, the coordinates are not correct.

For example in the `postprocess` function I think I am doing something wrong as the:

```
print(f"conf: {conf:.2f}")
print((xmin, ymin),(xmax, ymax))
```

returns:

```
conf: 0.50
(29012, 127753) (1270, 950)
```

Where the numbers `(29012, 127753)` to represent (xmin, ymin) aren't correct, I think this is outside the coordinates of the entire image. The original `image.shape` is `(960, 1280, 3)`.

Comment: What is `xmin = int(max((xmin * image.shape[1]), 10))` for? Why the multiplication?

Comment: Thanks for this.....am still learning, ha. I grabbed some of this code from a notebook provided by openVINO: https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_notebooks/blob/main/notebooks/115-async-api/115-async-api.ipynb

Comment: @Claudio would you know why in the link they have that odd multiplication? Would it be anything to do with like model scaling the data or something funny like that?

Comment: Yeah ... it's actually there in the demo-code of openVINO (so the code you grabbed has apparently a not yet reported/detected/corrected bug).

Comment: *Why the odd multiplication?* The multiplication does make sense in the context of pixel coordinates as floats normalized to have values from 0.0 to 1.0 for both the width and the height. Probably a copy/paste of code block which requires re-scaling to actual integer pixel coordinates. This explains also the probably unnecessary int() if xmin, ..., ymax are integers not floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want a margin of at least ten pixels from the image edges for drawing the bounding box, so you need:

```
            xmin = int(max(xmin, 10))
            ymin = int(max(ymin, 10))
            xmax = int(min(xmax, image.shape[1] - 10))
            ymax = int(min(ymax, image.shape[0] - 10))
```

And if xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax are already integers you don't need the int() wrapper.

Comment: So I did test this the model output values are floats....something is still off and I cant see any documentation on how to handle this. Posted a git issue here on Intels repo: https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/issues/3567